# Single array of objects sort and slice not working

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, slice

I have a single entry on a collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c6f7a5ef86bd1a5402e928"),
    "cid" : 1,
    "array1" : [
       { "type": "car", value: 20 },
       { "type": "bike", value: 50 },
       { "type": "bus", value: 5 },
       { "type": "cycle", value: 100 },
...... 9000 more entry something like this
     ],
"array2" : [
       { "type": "laptop", value: 200 },
       { "type": "desktop", value: 15 },
       { "type": "tablet", value: 55 },
       { "type": "mobile", value: 90 },
...... 9000 more entry something like this
     ]
}
```

Now I want to sort and slice the data for the pagination purpose.

For that I wrote the query which works well on slice case but not on sort case.
This is my query which works for slice case

```
let val = await SomeCollectionName.findOne(
{ cid: 1 },
{ _id: 1 , array1: { $slice: [0, 10] } } ---> its return the 10 data. Initially it return from 0 to 10, then next call $slice: [10, 10]
).exec();
if (val) {
  //console.log('Got the value')
}
console.log(error)
```

This is my query When I add sort with slice

```
let val = await SomeCollectionName.findOne(
{ cid: 1 },
{ _id: 1 , array1: { $sort: { value: -1 }, $slice: [0, 10] } }
).exec();
if (val) {
  //console.log('Got the value')
}
console.log(error)
```

Is there anyone who guide me where I'm wrong or suggest me what is the efficient way for getting the data.

> UPDATE

I am getting the answer from the above question and looking for the same implementation for two array.
Everything is same. Earlier I was dealing with 1 array now this time I have to deal with two array.

Just curious to know that how these things happen
I wrote the aggregation query but one array results is fine but others are returning the same data throughout the array.

This is my query as per the suggestion of dealing with single array with sort and slice

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "cid": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$array1"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$array2"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "array1.value": -1,
      "array2.value": -1,
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 3
  },
  {
   $group:{
    "_id":"$_id",
    "array1":{$push:"$array1"},
    "array2":{$push:"$array2"}
    }
   }
])
```

Comment: It shouldn't work. There is no $sort [projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that $sort is not supported by findOne() in its projection parameter.

You can instead use aggregation to achieve the expected result,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "cid": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$array1"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "array1.value": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 3
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "array1": {
        $push: {
          "type": "$array1.type",
          "value": "$array1.value"
        }
      },
      "array2": {
        "$first": "$array2"
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$array2"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "array2.value": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 3
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "array2": {
        $push: {
          "type": "$array2.type",
          "value": "$array2.value"
        }
      },
      "array1": {
        "$first": "$array1"
      }
    },
    
  }
])
```

[Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: Is it possible to do same thing for two array on same query. Like currently We are sorting and slicing the single array

Comment: Yes , you can unwind the second array as well.

Comment: I tried but one array data is returning fine but other one is returning the same data throughout the array

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you check and suggest me

Comment: You cant unwind array2 right after array1. Because you are unwinding the output from the previous stage which is unwind of array1. What u can do in this case is apply the same stages from $unwind after the $group of array1, thought that doesnt sound like the best method to me.

Comment: I tried that approach also but not getting the right answer

Comment: i updated the answer with what i mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: can you share the unwind part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234320/discussion-between-fractal397-and-aks).